# Taylor/Laurent series question for $\cot(\pi z)$;where did $1/n$ come from?

Tags: complex-analysis

> [image]

I am having a panic attack right now so I can't see this immediately.

But where did $\frac{1}{z - n} + \frac{1}{n}$ come from (yes I know its from the sum, but where did the summand come from?).

Do they mean $\frac{1}{z - n } - \frac{1}{0 - n}$?

BY the way, $M(\Bbb C)$ means the meromorphic functions on $\Bbb C$. This is taken as an example for the Mittag-Leffler Theorem in Complex Analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Why $\dfrac{1}{z-n} + \dfrac{1}{n}$?  Well, $1/(z-n)$ is the most obvious function that has principal part $1/(z-n)$ at $z=n$.  The problem with this is that  if you just tried $\sum_{n \ne 0} 1/(z-n)$, the sum wouldn't converge anywhere, because $1/(z-n) \approx -1/n$ as $n \to \infty$ and $\sum_n 1/n$ diverges.  So you add that $1/n$, and then $1/(z-n) + 1/n \approx -z/n^2$, whose sum over $n \ne 0$ 
 converges nicely.

Comment: "$because 1/(z−n)≈-1/n$ as $n\to \infty $", you mean to say $z\to \infty$?

Comment: Oh I think you mean to say $1/(z - n) \approx -1/z$

Comment: No, $z$ is fixed and $n \to \infty$.  I meant what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I found a link to a paper that may help :

http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/311/cotan.pdf

Comment: That one kind of works backwards.